# How to deploy a module in an Alfresco deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, alfresco

I have successfully deployed alfresco community 4.2.f in a Tomcat 7.0.59 with a database MySQL5.6 and jdk1.8.0_141

No problems thus far, now, I got a module developed by our company which I need to be deployed in alfresco. This module invokes a WS which will send a PDF to some place.

I got this module in a jar compiled with jdk1.8.0_141

I tried to put it inside the alfresco.war before deployment in Tomcat in WEB-INF/lib but when I do that and deploy with startup.bat from Tomcat it pops in the console

```
instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/xfire/XFireRuntimeException
```

I understand this exception is caused by putting the jar inside the war.
I was told that the jar was compiled also in jdk8.

Also, tell you that if instead of this jar I put inside the alfresco.war in WEB-INF/classes a properties file to get our database in deployment it works fine.

The problem is when I try to deploy the module.

I saw there are quite tutorials pointing to do something like:

```
java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar
```

I can't do that because this is done installing alfresco with its wizard I assume. I did it deploying alfresco in a fresh tomcat installation.

Does anyone know how to deploy our module with the way we deployed alfresco? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the module you made is a jar instead of a amp. So if you have external dependencies, they won't be included in your packaging : "Simple JAR modules are generally the preferred type of packaging for extensions where dependencies on third-party libraries do not exist." You should use one of the solutions I gave you lower.

Comment: i just saw this comment, this jar hasn't got third-party libraries, then it is preferred with a jar, right? then it whould be possible to deploy the extension in one of the ways i told you i did right?

Comment: It is hard to say since you manually put a jar in the WAR: I can't garanty you that it is ok, sorry.

Comment: i found what was the problem, first as i told you in a comment on your post, it wasn't compiled with jdk8, but that is not the only issue, the depedencies are not updated to alfresco 4.2.f, they are updated for the previous alfresco where it was deployed, 2.1.0. Do you know a way to check or to know which are the compatible dependencies for the new pom.xml?

Comment: i focused too much on that i was deploying it wrong, but the problem was the code in the module....

Comment: I would suggest you to watch the dependencies in the lib folder of your war, or make a mvn dependency:tree on the parent pom of the alfresco sdk.

Comment: i got the jars in my local repository but when i do the mvn clean install it seems that is not able to find it, it throws me this:  The POM for org.alfresco:alfresco-repository:jar:4.2.f is missing, no
y information available

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to install your amp :

**The first traditional one :**

This is the one installed with the apply amp procédure (alfresco-mmt).
To me, this is not true that it is not compatible with your installation. You can easily find the bin folder (containing the alfresco-mmt.jar file) here in the alfresco packaging : https://download.alfresco.com/release/community/4.2.f-build-00012/alfresco-community-4.2.f.zip

When you have it, you can follow the documentation : http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/amp-install.html

And apply your amp for example following this way :

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation>
```

**The second one :**

You can recreate the war with the alfresco sdk and include in the build the module you created.
If you follow this documentation : http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-tutorials-all-in-one-archetype.html
the war produced in the target folder of the **repo** part will contain your module, since the pom of this module will contains a dependency to the **amp** module :

```
...
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
          <type>war</type>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Demonstrating the dependency on the repo AMP developed in the 'amp' 
                           module -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
          <artifactId>my-amp</artifactId>
          <version>${my-amp.version}</version>
          <type>amp</type>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      ...
      <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                         <configuration>
                         <!-- Here is can control the order of overlay of your (WAR, AMP, etc.) 
                                              dependencies | NOTE: At least one WAR dependency must be uncompressed first 
                                              | NOTE: In order to have a dependency effectively added to the WAR you need 
                                               to | explicitly mention it in the overlay section. | NOTE: First-win resource 
                                              strategy is used by the WAR plugin -->
                                 <overlays>
                                 <!-- Current project customizations -->
                                       <overlay />
                                       <!-- The Alfresco WAR -->
                                       <overlay>
                                           <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                                           <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
                                           <type>war</type>
                                            <!-- To allow inclusion of META-INF -->
                                            <excludes />
                                             </overlay>
                                            <!-- Add / order your AMPs here -
                                        <overlay>
                                             <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
                                             <artifactId>my-amp</artifactId>
                                             <type>amp</type>
                                         </overlay>
                                       </overlays>
                               </configuration>
                      </plugin>
               </plugins>
       </build>
```

Comment: What i did to deploy alfresco was to put the alfresco.war and share.war you can get from this distribution in alfresco-community-4.2.f.zip\web-server\webapps inside apache-tomcat-7.0.59\webapps, then startup.bat from apache-tomcat-7.0.59/bin. When i did that in the folder alfresco inside the webapp i can not see the bin folder

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your problem. Can you clarify what your problem is then ?

Comment: i would like to use the first solution you propose, but when i deployed alfresco in tomcat as i told you i don't have a bin folder inside tomcat/webapps/alfresco. The only bin folder i see is the one from tomcat, i list you the directories i have inside tomcat/webapps/alfresco to clarify what i have: META-INF, WEB-INF, cmis-browser-app, cmisfs, css, css-boilerplate, favicon.ico, images, index.jsp, jsp, scripts, services, swf, wsdl, yui

Comment: i also tried to create tomcat/shared/classes and tomcat/shared/lib and set in catalina.properties this: shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/classes, ${catalina.base}/shared/lib    When i did again the startup.bat it didn't recognize my jar because i couldn't do the actions it does when supposedly deployed the jar module

Comment: Ok, what I meant is that you can copy the bin folder at the root of the alfresco-community-4.2.f.zip archive in the root folder of your tomcat (or just the mmt jar anywhere), and then use the command java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation>. to integrate your amp the good way.

Comment: Hi again, i asked in the company and they told me that never had to use the amp method, i also just saw with java-decompiler that the jar is not compiled with jdk8, instead it is compiled with jdk6, im gonna make some adjustments and try again, if i am not successful i will try your method. Either way i will post the solution when i find it. Thanks for your time @Akah